# TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len(), in 2 parts of the code

Tags: python

I'm working on a hangman game, and I keep running into the same error, and I've been trying to debug it for a couple hours with no progress.

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "hangman.py", line 128, in <module>
       guess = guessletter(miss + correct)
   File "hangman.py", line 103, in guessletter
       if len(guess) != 1:
   TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

Line 98 - 110

```
`def guessletter(previousguess):   #this function lets the player guess a letter, and see if the guess is acceptable
    while True:
        print ('Guess a Letter')
        guess = input()
        guess = guess.lower     
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print ('Enter single letter please.')
        elif guess in previousguess:
            print ('That letter was already guessed. Choose another')
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print ('Please put a letter')
        else:
            return guess`
```

## Line 125~141

```
while True:
board(hangmanpictures, miss, correct, unknownword)   #i define a board function at the top

guess = guessletter(miss + correct)   #i use the function defined above, but it seems to make an error here..

if guess in unknownword:
    correct = correct + guess

    foundallletters = True    #check if player has won
    for k in range(len(unknownword)):
        if unknownword[k] not in correct:
            foundallletters = False
            break

    if foundallletters:
        print ('The secret word is "' + unknownword + '"! You won!')
        gamefinish = True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
guess = guess.lower
```

You forgot to call the `str.lower` method so `guess` is being assigned to the method object itself.

To fix the problem, call the method by placing `()` after its name:

```
guess = guess.lower()
#                  ^^
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> guess = 'ABCDE'
>>> guess = guess.lower
>>> guess
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x014FA740>
>>>
>>> guess = 'ABCDE'
>>> guess = guess.lower()
>>> guess
'abcde'
>>>
```